# Import Error : attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

Can you please tell me how to do relative import correctly.

Project Structure:

```
p1
|-  x1
|  |-  __init__.py
|  |-  x1_module1.py
|- x2
   |-  __init__.py
   |-  x2_module1.py
```

In x2_modules.py

```py
try:
    from p1.x1.x1_module import temp_func
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed "from p1.x1.x1_module import temp_func"')
    print(e)

try:
    from .x1.x1_module import temp_func
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed "from .x1.x1_module import temp_func"')
    print(e)

try:
    from ..x1.x1_module import temp_func
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed "from ..x1.x1_module import temp_func"')
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
Failed "from p1.x1.x1_module import temp_func"
No module named 'p1'
Failed "from .x1.x1_module import temp_func"
attempted relative import with no known parent package
Failed "from ..x1.x1_module import temp_func"
attempted relative import with no known parent package
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

For more understanding, please take a look at this image:
[image]

Comment: Is this package installed? It all depends on where your python path is. If the parent directory to `p1` was in the path, this would all work because `p1` would be recognized as a package.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

If your python script is called from the p1 directory, this should work:

```
from x1.x1_module1 import temp_func
```

To see a list of where python is searching for your module, use this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The first entry of sys.path should be the directory your script is running from, which I'm assuming is p1

Answer (score -1):

Project Structure:

```
p1
|-  x1
|  |-  __init__.py
|  |-  x1_module1.py
|- x2
   |-  __init__.py
   |-  x2_module1.py
```

Edit: The code wasn't following PEP-8 and was hard to read. I, thus, optimized it.

Please try this code:

```
import sys
import os

PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(),
            os.path.expanduser(__file__)
            )
        )
    )

sys.path.append(
    os.path.normpath(
        os.path.join(
            SCRIPT_DIR,
            PACKAGE_PARENT
            )
        )
    )

from x1.x1_module import tempfunction
```

It works

Regards
Ishaan Kapoor